# PDO Insert query in table in another database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I want to make a sendmail function on my program. But first, I want to store the information: send_to, subject, and message in a table in another database(mes) where automail is performed. The problem is data fetched from another database(pqap) are not being added on the table(email_queue) in database(mes).

In this code, I have a table where all databases in the server are stored. I made a query to select a specific database.

```
$sql5 = "SELECT pl.database, pl.name FROM product_line pl WHERE visible = 1 AND name='PQ AP'";
$dbh = db_connect("mes");
$stmt5 = $dbh->prepare($sql5);
$stmt5->execute();
$data = $stmt5->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$dbh=null;
```

Then after selecting the database,it has a query for selecting the information in the table on the selected database. Here's the code.

```
foreach ($data as $row5)  GenerateEmail($row5['database'], $row5['name']);
```

Then this is part (I think) is not working. I don't know what's the problem.

```
function GenerateEmail($database, $line) {

$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice WHERE ID=:id6";

$dbh = db_connect($database);
$stmt6 = $dbh->prepare($sql6);
$stmt6->bindParam(':id6', $_POST['idtxt'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt6->execute();
$data = $stmt6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$dbh=null;


foreach ($data as $row6) {

$invnumb=$row6['Invoice_Number'];
$partnumb=$row6['Part_Number'];
$issue=$row6['Issues'];
$pic=$row6['PIC_Comments'];
$emailadd= $row6['PersoninCharge'];

if($row6['Status']=="Open") {

    $message = "<html><b>Invoice Number: {$invnumb}.</b><br><br>";
    $message .= "<b>Part Number:</b><br><xmp>{$partnumb}</xmp><br><br>";
    $message .= "<b>Issues:</b><br><xmp>{$issue}</xmp><br>";  
    $message .= "<b>{$pic}<b><br>";  
    $message .= "</html>";
    if(!empty($emailadd)) {
    dbInsertEmailMessage($emailadd, "Invoice Number: {$invnumb} - {$issue}.", $message);
    $dbh=null;
    }
    }

}
}

function dbInsertEmailMessage($send_to, $subject, $message) {

$sql7 = "INSERT INTO email_queue (Send_to, Subject, Message) VALUES (:send_to, :subject, :message)";    
$dbh = db_connect("mes");
$stmt7 = $dbh->prepare($sql7); 
$stmt7->bindParam(':send_to', $send_to, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt7->bindParam(':subject', $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt7->bindParam(':message', $message, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt7->execute();
$dbh=null;
}
```

Here's my db connection:

```
function db_connect($DATABASE) {

session_start();

// Connection data (server_address, database, username, password)
    $servername = '*****';
    //$namedb = '****';
    $userdb = '*****';
    $passdb = '*****';

    // Display message if successfully connect, otherwise retains and outputs the potential error
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$DATABASE", $userdb, $passdb, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        return $dbh;
        //echo 'Connected to database';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
}
```

Comment: how your db_connect function looks like?

Comment: i added my db connection. see above. thanks

Comment: You have `$dbh=null;` repeated inside `GenerateEmail()`. Does `dbInsertEmailMessage()` function open another connection?

Comment: Yes it will open another connection because the query will be on the other database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that may help with your failed inserts. See if this is what you are looking for, I have notated important points to consider:

```
<?php
// take session_start() out of your database connection function
// it draws an error when you call it more than once
session_start();
// Create a connection class
class   DBConnect
    {
        public function connect($settings = false)
            {
                $host       =   (!empty($settings['host']))? $settings['host'] : false;
                $username   =   (!empty($settings['username']))? $settings['username'] : false;
                $password   =   (!empty($settings['password']))? $settings['password'] : false;
                $database   =   (!empty($settings['database']))? $settings['database'] : false;

                try {
                        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                        // You return the connection before it hits that setting
                        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
                        return $dbh;
                    }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                        // Only return the error if an admin is logged in
                        // you may reveal too much about your database on failure
                        return false;
                        //echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
            }
    }
// Make a specific connection selector
// Put in your database credentials for all your connections
function use_db($database = false)
    {
        $con    =   new DBConnect();

        if($database == 'mes')
            return $con->connect(array("database"=>"db1","username"=>"u1","password"=>"p1","host"=>"localhost"));
        else
            return $con->connect(array("database"=>"db2","username"=>"u2","password"=>"p2","host"=>"localhost"));
    }
// Create a query class to return selects
function query($con,$sql,$bind=false)
    {
        if(empty($bind))
            $query  =   $con->query($sql);
        else {
                foreach($bind as $key => $value) {
                        $kBind              =   ":{$key}";
                        $bindVals[$kBind]   =   $value;
                    }

                $query = $con->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute($bindVals);
            }

        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $result[]   =   $row;
            }

        return (!empty($result))? $result:0;
    }
// Create a write function that will write to database
function write($con,$sql,$bind=false)
    {
        if(empty($bind))
            $query  =   $con->query($sql);
        else {
                foreach($bind as $key => $value) {
                        $kBind              =   ":{$key}";
                        $bindVals[$kBind]   =   $value;
                    }

                $query = $con->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute($bindVals);
            }
    }

// Do not create connections in your function(s), rather pass them into the functions
// so you can use the same db in and out of functions
// Also do not null the connections out
function GenerateEmail($con,$conMes,$line = false)
    {
        if(empty($_POST['idtxt']) || (!empty($_POST['idtxt']) && !is_numeric($_POST['idtxt'])))
            return false;

        $data   =   query($con,"SELECT * FROM `invalid_invoice` WHERE `ID` = :0", array($_POST['idtxt']));

        if($data == 0)
            return false;

        // Instead of creating a bunch of inserts, instead create an array
        // to build multiple rows, then insert only once
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($data as $row) {
                $invnumb    =   $row['Invoice_Number'];
                $partnumb   =   $row['Part_Number'];
                $issue      =   $row['Issues'];
                $pic        =   $row['PIC_Comments'];
                $emailadd   =   $row['PersoninCharge'];

                if($row['Status']=="Open") {
                        ob_start();
?><html>
    <b>Invoice Number: <?php echo $invnumb;?></b><br><br>
    <b>Part Number:</b><br><xmp><?php echo $partnumb; ?></xmp><br><br>
    <b>Issues:</b><br><xmp><?php echo $issue; ?></xmp><br>
    <b><?php echo $pic; ?><b><br>
</html>
<?php
                        $message    =   ob_get_contents();
                        ob_end_clean();

                        if(!empty($emailadd)) {
                                $bind["{$i}to"]     =   $emailadd;
                                $bind["{$i}subj"]   =   "Invoice Number: {$invnumb} - {$issue}.";
                                $bind["{$i}msg"]    =   htmlspecialchars($message,ENT_QUOTES);

                                $sql[]  =   "(:{$i}to, :{$i}subj, :{$i}msg)";
                            }
                    }

                $i++;
            }

        if(!empty($sql))
            return dbInsertEmailMessage($conMes,$sql,$bind);

        return false;
    }

function dbInsertEmailMessage($con,$sql_array,$bind)
    {    
        if(!is_array($sql_array))
            return false;

        write($con,"INSERT INTO `email_queue` (`Send_to`, `Subject`, `Message`) VALUES ".implode(", ",$sql_array),$bind);

        return true;
    }   

// Create connections
$con    =   use_db();
$conMes =   use_db('mes');
GenerateEmail($con,$conMes);
```